# TensorFlow 2.0: InvalidArgumentError: device CUDA:0 not supported by XLA service while setting up XLA_GPU_JIT device number 0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am using TensorFlow 2.0 and Python 3.7 for CIFAR-10 classification.

Dimensions of training and testing sets are:

X_train.shape = (50000, 32, 32, 3), y_train.shape = (50000, 10)

X_test.shape = (10000, 32, 32, 3), y_test.shape = (10000, 10)

But, when I execute the following code:

```
# Create training and testing datasets-
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))
```

It gives me the error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 # Create training and testing datasets-
>   ----> 2 train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
>         3 test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py
>   in from_tensor_slices(tensors)
>       433       Dataset: A `Dataset`.
>       434     """
>   --> 435     return TensorSliceDataset(tensors)
>       436 
>       437   class _GeneratorState(object):
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py
>   in **init**(self, element)    2352   def **init**(self, element):
>   2353     """See `Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` for details."""
>   -> 2354     element = structure.normalize_element(element)    2355     batched_spec = structure.type_spec_from_value(element)    2356
>   self._tensors = structure.to_batched_tensor_list(batched_spec,
>   element)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/util/structure.py
>   in normalize_element(element)
>       109         else:
>       110           normalized_components.append(
>   --> 111               ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="component_%d" % i))
>       112   return nest.pack_sequence_as(element, normalized_components)
>       113
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py
>   in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint) 
>   1182   preferred_dtype = deprecation.deprecated_argument_lookup(
>   1183       "dtype_hint", dtype_hint, "preferred_dtype",
>   preferred_dtype)
>   -> 1184   return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)    1185     1186
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py
>   in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)    1240
>   name=name,    1241       preferred_dtype=dtype_hint,
>   -> 1242       as_ref=False)    1243     1244
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py
>   in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref,
>   preferred_dtype, ctx, accept_composite_tensors)    1294     1295
>   if ret is None:
>   -> 1296       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)    1297     1298     if ret is NotImplemented:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py
>   in _default_conversion_function(***failed resolving arguments***)
>        50 def _default_conversion_function(value, dtype, name, as_ref):
>        51   del as_ref  # Unused.
>   ---> 52   return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
>        53 
>        54
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py
>   in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
>       225   """
>       226   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
>   --> 227                         allow_broadcast=True)
>       228 
>       229
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py
>   in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape,
>   allow_broadcast)
>       233   ctx = context.context()
>       234   if ctx.executing_eagerly():
>   --> 235     t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
>       236     if shape is None:
>       237       return t
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py
>   in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
>        93     except AttributeError:
>        94       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
>   ---> 95   ctx.ensure_initialized()
>        96   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
>        97
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py
>   in ensure_initialized(self)
>       490         if self._default_is_async == ASYNC:
>       491           pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(opts, True)
>   --> 492         self._context_handle = pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_NewContext(opts)
>       493       finally:
>       494         pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_DeleteContextOptions(opts)
>
> InvalidArgumentError: device CUDA:0 not supported by XLA service
>     while setting up XLA_GPU_JIT device number 0

I also tried the following code to fix the error:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
```

When I execute the following code:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')

gpus
[]
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same issues with you. The cause might be that the GPU device your progress selected doesn't have enough gpu-memory to run your progress.

My solution is：

1. Add `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=*` to your training/testing script (`.sh` file). Example: `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python3 train_cifar.py`
2. Add this line in your training`.py` file: `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'`

Tips: the GPU ids in step-1 and step-2 must be matched.

(When I first met this error, I also had `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']='0'` in my code, but the process seems to still select device cuda:1 for training, wired... But adopting step-1 solves my problem, I hope it can solve yours too.)